# How to access a popup menu on CardView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, popupmenu

I have a recyclerview where there is an image for a popup menu in recylerview item (see the image below), so I created a popup menu with edit and delete option on cardView I have tried the below code but when I click on the popup menu button, nothing's happening
In my NotesAdapter I want to retrieve data

[image]

Here is my **item.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menuIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_popup_menu" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Section"
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Here is my **NotesAdapter.java**

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.MyHolder>
{

    List<Listdata> noteslist;
    private Context context;
    public  NotesAdapter(List<Listdata> noteslist,Context context)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.noteslist=noteslist;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,viewGroup,false);

        MyHolder myHolder=new MyHolder(view);
        return myHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder, int position) {
        final Listdata data=noteslist.get(position);
        myHolder.title.setText(data.getTitle());
        myHolder.desc.setText(data.getDesc());



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return noteslist.size();
    }


    class  MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        TextView title,desc;

        public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            desc=itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Listdata listdata=noteslist.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    Intent i=new Intent(context, StreamActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("id",listdata.id);
                    i.putExtra("title",listdata.title);
                    i.putExtra("desc",listdata.desc);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            ImageView menuIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.menuIcon);
            menuIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), v);
                    menu.setGravity(Gravity.END);
                    menu.getMenu().add("Edit").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                            Listdata listdata=noteslist.get(getAdapterPosition());
                            Intent i=new Intent(context, EditActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("id",listdata.id);
                            i.putExtra("title",listdata.title);
                            i.putExtra("desc",listdata.desc);
                            context.startActivity(i);

                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    menu.getMenu().add("Delete").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                }
            });


        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyHolder myHolder, final int position) {
    final Listdata data=noteslist.get(position);
    myHolder.title.setText(data.getTitle());
    myHolder.desc.setText(data.getDesc());
    myHolder.menuIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, myHolder.menuIcon);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_edit:
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Edit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent i=new Intent(context, EditActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("id",data.id);
                            i.putExtra("title",data.title);
                            i.putExtra("desc",data.desc);
                            context.startActivity(i);
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_delete:
                            noteslist.remove(position);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
            popupMenu.show();
        }
    });



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return noteslist.size();
}


class  MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    TextView title,desc;
    ImageView menuIcon;

    public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        menuIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.menuIcon);
        title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        desc=itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Listdata listdata=noteslist.get(getAdapterPosition());
                Intent i=new Intent(context, StreamActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id",listdata.id);
                i.putExtra("title",listdata.title);
                i.putExtra("desc",listdata.desc);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: My pleasure.. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have seen in your code that you are just creating popup menu object but not showing
to show a popup menu follow below code.

```
private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
    // inflate menu
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_album, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
    popup.show();
}
```